# How to supply an Rxjs observable as data for a method using combineLatest in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I currently have a `combineLatest` method, which I am supplying through my class:

```
export class ObservableDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  private value: any[];
  private key: string;
  constructor(value: any[], key) {
    super();
    this.value = value;
    this.key = key;
  }

  connect() {
    //Code related to question starts here
    return combineLatest(this.value, (data) => {
      return data[this.key];
    });
    //Code related to question ends here
  }

  disconnect() {} 
}
```

In my unit test, I have a beforeEach, I am using to instantiate the component and supply an observable:

```
const dummyData = [{
  visible: {
    data: 'test123'
  }
}];
const observableDummyData = Observable.of([dummyData]);
beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: ObservableDataSource, useValue: new ObservableDataSource(observableDummyData, 'visible')}
  ]
});
});

  it('should be created', inject([ObservableDataSource], (service: ObservableDataSource) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

The only issue, is when looking at the console for karma runner, while this.value is showing up as an observable, data being emmitted from combineLatest is showing up as empty `TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined`. Possible reasons why:

1. I am supplying the data wrong to `Observable.of`
2. I am creating an observable the wrong way(I should not be using observable.of).
3. I have an emitter that I need to call, in order for the observable data to be passed to combineLatest.
4. Reason I have not discovered

Any suggestions, are more than appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are multiple issues in your code.

**1.**
Your service expect its `value` parameter to be an array, but you are providing a simple Observable.

**2**
`combineLatest` works with multiple observable parameters, not an array of parameters.

```
return combineLatest(obsA, obsB, obsC, (a, b, c) => { ... });

// or with the spreading operator
return combineLatest(...arrayOfObs).map((...data) => { ... });
```

### Code example (not tested)

#### Dummy data

```
const dummyData1 = [{
  visible: {
    data: 'test123'
  }
}];

const dummyData2 = [{
  visible: {
    data: 'somethingElse'
  }
}];


const observableDummyData = [
  Observable.of(dummyData1),
  Observable.of(dummyData2),
];
```

#### combineLatest

See [documentation for spreading operator](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html)

```
connect() {
    return combineLatest(...this.value).pipe(
        map(...data) => {
            return data[this.key]
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Just for curiosity sake, how would I go ahead and create the dummyData as an observable parameter?

Comment: @Master-Chief edited with some example. Be careful, I wrote it without testing, there is maybe some typo error.

Comment: Thank you. When using obversable.of I still receive the error in my unit test: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined`

Comment: I'm going to update the question, I think I wasn't clear.

Comment: Question updated. Just pointed out, that observable.of is giving me an observable, but combineLatest just isn't returning any data.

Comment: How did you test it? Can you add the code where you actually subscribe to the combined observables?

Comment: That is a good point. The combineLatest is not actually be subscribed in this class. It is simply being used as a way to pass the stream. I should create a spy for this one.

Comment: `data` inside of the map is an array of objects. So you'd need to grab the first item out of the array before using the key to get the value. Are you sure you don't want a merge here?

Comment: @AustinMatherne When trying to reproduce this problem, I was asking to myself the same question. I don't think the combineLatest operator is a good choice here.

Comment: The reason I am using combineLatest, is because it has a projection function, which allows the data to be returned right away: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

In addition, for the component I am using, it is important that they all have access to each other at any given time.